# how to get the value of multiple select

Tags: php, html

How can I get & write the value in

```
{ shell_exec(" ./write_in_file 'write the select value  exactly here ' "); }
```

I have a shell code that write the text in a file.
Here's the code:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <select name="t[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
    <option value="3">thired</option>
  </select>
  <input name="save" type="submit" />
  <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'save'])){ $test=$_POST[ 't']; if($test){ shell_exec( "./write_in_file 'some text <?php foreach($test as $a){echo $a."\n ";} ?> ' " ); }} ?>
</form>
```

Comment: <form method="POST">   
<select name="t[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">thired</option>
</select>
    <input name="save" type="submit" />
<?php if (isset($_POST['save'])){
  $test=$_POST['t'];
  if($test){
  shell_exec( "./write_in_file 'some text <?php foreach($test as $a){echo $a."\n";} ?> ' " );
}}
?>
</form>

Comment: Taking a look now. Why use shell to write to the file when PHP has functions for it? [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very strange way to write data from HTML select to a file. I recommend using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). It's very easy to work with and more secure.

If you want to stick with shell-exec then [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will help to glue pieces together:

```
<form method="POST">
  <select name="t[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
  </select>
  <input name="save" type="submit" />
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['save'])){ 
        $test=$_POST['t']; 
        if($test){ 
            shell_exec( "./write_in_file 'some text ". implode("\n ", $test) . "\n ' " ); 
        }
    } 
?>
</form>
```